# How do I prevent 3rd party application from loading custom ".style" files?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, style, framework, geosoft

*Backround:* I run Geosoft Target on my machine which has some compatibility functionality with ArcGIS. (mxd conversion, export to, etc.)  I use the Geosoft Target application "stand-alone" and never use the ArcGIS funcions.

*Issue:* Target installs a ".style" file in ints instalation directory which appears in the Styel manager.  If i uncheck the GEosoft Target ".style" file do clear it from the Style Manager it succeeds only in the current local session - the next time i open any other ArcMap doceument including the one in which i disabled it, the style file is automatically re-loaded.

The one possible patchwork solution would be to delete the Geosoft ".style" file but I am more interested in doing it properly in ArcGIS - **is there a global setting that prevents 3rd party syle files from loading?**

[image]

Comment: You might try creating a blank text file, renaming it to whatever Geostyle creates, and set it to read-only. When ArcGIS tries to read it it will hopefully fail gracefully and just skip it.

Comment: Thanks, good idea. I am slightly unhappy about this app messing around with the default framework. I failed to mention that in order to be able to read some "Geosoft" proprietary spatial formats i have to install a plugin. I will try uninstalling it to see if that works.

Comment: I guess the other thing is, what makes this a problem for you? Is it just OCD? :)

Comment: My OCD is partially to blame but I also have a LOT of custom symbols which slows down cartography work significantly. (I do a ton of cartography by manually placing and creating complex symbols and labels - constantly drilling through all levels of symbol menus some of which take 6 - 7 seconds to refresh. Humming the "Jeopardy" tune helps but not always...) Extra "style" databases make it even worse.   I already consolidated everything into a single style files (from 4 different ones) and removed all duplicates, compacted the mdb. It's better but that surprise style pack needs to go...